# Python bot randomly skipping lines

Tags: python, pycharm, macros, bots

I'm writing a python bot for a game. The problem is that sometimes the bot seems to be skipping lines. I also get tracebacks in console for idk what reason actually. I'm using PyCharm and python 3.11. I'm new to python so I might be missing something.

Code:

```
from pyautogui import *
import ctypes
import time
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import random
import win32api, win32con
import cv2


SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

# C struct redefinitions
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def sekwencja():
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.109)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.125)
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.181)
    PressKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.219)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.103)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.119)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.063)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.118)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.203)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.016)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(208)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ReleaseKey(208)

def run():
    time.sleep(1)
    PressKey(2)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(2)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    PressKey(30)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(30)
    time.sleep(1.4)
    PressKey(29)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(29)
    time.sleep(1.35)
    PressKey(20)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(20)
    time.sleep(3)

    #sekwencja()
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.109)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.125)
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.181)
    PressKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.219)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.103)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.119)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.063)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.118)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.203)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.016)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(208)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ReleaseKey(208)

    time.sleep(3.5)

    PressKey(3)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(3)
    PressKey(33)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(33)
    time.sleep(3)
    PressKey(31)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(31)
    time.sleep(1)
    PressKey(29)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(29)
    time.sleep(1.35)
    PressKey(4)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(4)

    time.sleep(5)

    PressKey(20)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(20)
    time.sleep(1)

    #sekwencja()
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.109)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.125)
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.181)
    PressKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.219)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.103)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.119)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.063)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.118)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.203)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.016)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(208)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ReleaseKey(208)

    time.sleep(3.5)

    PressKey(5)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(5)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    PressKey(33)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(33)
    time.sleep(3)
    PressKey(30)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(30)
    time.sleep(1.4)
    PressKey(31)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(31)
    time.sleep(1)
    PressKey(29)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(29)
    PressKey(6)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(6)

    time.sleep(4)

    PressKey(20)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(20)
    time.sleep(3)

    #sekwencja()
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.109)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.125)
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.181)
    PressKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.219)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.103)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.119)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.063)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.118)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.203)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.016)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(208)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ReleaseKey(208)

    time.sleep(3.5)

    PressKey(33)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(33)
    time.sleep(3)

    #sekwencja()
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.109)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.125)
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.181)
    PressKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.219)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.103)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.119)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.063)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.118)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.203)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.016)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(208)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ReleaseKey(208)

    time.sleep(3.5)

    PressKey(2)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(2)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    PressKey(20)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(20)
    time.sleep(3)
    PressKey(30)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(30)
    time.sleep(1.4)
    PressKey(31)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(31)
    time.sleep(1)
    PressKey(29)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(29)
    time.sleep(1.35)
    PressKey(3)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(3)

    time.sleep(4)

    PressKey(33)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(33)
    time.sleep(3)

    #sekwencja()
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.109)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.125)
    PressKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.181)
    PressKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.047)
    ReleaseKey(44)
    time.sleep(0.219)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.103)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.119)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.063)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.118)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.104)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.203)
    PressKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.062)
    ReleaseKey(45)
    time.sleep(0.094)
    ReleaseKey(200)
    time.sleep(0.016)
    ReleaseKey(205)
    time.sleep(0.078)
    PressKey(208)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    ReleaseKey(208)

    time.sleep(3.5)

    PressKey(4)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(4)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    PressKey(20)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(20)
    time.sleep(3)
    PressKey(31)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(31)



def retry():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    PressKey(28)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(28)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    PressKey(28)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(28)
    PressKey(28)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(28)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    PressKey(28)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(28)

def remap():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    PressKey(66)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(66)
    time.sleep(1)
    PressKey(66)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(66)
    time.sleep(1)
    PressKey(66)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    ReleaseKey(66)

while True:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('start.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.6) != None:
        print('run')
        run()
    else:
        pass

    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('remap.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.8) != None:
        print('remapf8')
        remap()
    else:
        pass

    #if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('retry.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.8) != None:
        #print('retryEnter')
        #retry()
    #else:
        #pass
```

Tracebacks:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dorii\PycharmProjects\sdrunner — kopia\spammer.py", line 680, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\dorii\PycharmProjects\sdrunner — kopia\spammer.py", line 245, in run
    time.sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I was calling function 'sekwencja()' mid-macro and thought this might be the problem but it didnt change anything, another thing I tried was deleting while and if's at the end of the code simply placing function 'run()' there but it also didnt change anything.